# vdots without padding above, perfectly vertically centered

Tags: typography

I like to use `\vdots` to obtain pictures like that (without the fbox of course):

[image]

The problem is that the `\vdots` are not vertically centered (the height is huge), and the dots are therefore not placed correctly on the picture. Ideally, I'd like a version of `\vdots` with the good height, and no depth (to ensure the shape is symetric), so that I can use `\raisebox{-.5\height}{\cvdots}` for instance to center it around baseline.

Comment: Use the optional parameters o\f `\raisebox` to cut off any depth or height you don't need. Like this: `\raisebox{distance}[extend-above][extend-below]{text}` [http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_148.html](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_148.html)

Comment: Thanks for the trick. It's just a bit annoying because I've to fine-tune it to find the appropriate parameters. I also found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282403/why-does-whitespace-above-vdots-disappear-in-bmatrix which provides a different method by stacking \hbox{.}, not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: Stacking `\hbox{.}` is exactly how `\vdots` id defined to begin with.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528775/82917 (shameless self-publicity).

Comment: @campa thanks a lot, it works great! I posted an answer based on yours, with also alignment for math.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Mathematical optimization problem doesn't look good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286701)  (More shameless self-publicity.)

Comment: @campa -- There were already three listings for `\vdots` in the [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2425) list, under "Math".  But your answer is also good, so I've added it, to give another option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to campa's comment (thanks!), I derived these many versions:

- above baseline
- aligned for math
- centered on baseline
- horizontal and centered on baseline

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\makeatletter
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528774/excess-vertical-space-in-vdots/528775#528775
\DeclareRobustCommand\cvdotsAboveBaseline{%
  \vbox{\baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@%
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}
}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cvdotsCenterMathline}{%
  % vcenter is used to center the argument on the 'math axis', which is at half the height of an 'x', or about the position of a minus sign.
  \vcenter{\cvdotsAboveBaseline}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cvdotsCenterBaseline}{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{%
    $\cvdotsAboveBaseline$%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\chdots}{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{%
    \rotatebox{90}{% Maybe better options than rotatebox...
      $\cvdotsAboveBaseline$%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\chdotsLdots}{% Has a small space on the right and left, which chdots does not have 
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-.5\totalheight\relax}{$\ldots$}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=red] (A) {A};
  \node[fill=blue,below=of A] (B) {B};
  \path (A) -- (B) node[midway,anchor=center] {\makebox[0pt][r]{$n$ }$\cvdotsCenterMathline$};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Show baseline then vdots:
Order: Original, above baseline, aligned for math, centered on baseline, horizontal and centered on baseline (2 versions):\\
ABCp\rule{2cm}{0.1pt}\fbox{$\vdots$}\fbox{$\cvdotsAboveBaseline$}\fbox{$\cvdotsCenterMathline$}\fbox{$\cvdotsCenterBaseline$}\fbox{$\chdots$}\fbox{$\chdotsLdots$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe you are making stuff much more complicated that it needs to be... in particular, what's the advantage of rotating vertically stacked dots over using the good old `\ldots`?

Comment: I guess `\ldots` could be fine (at least it has a symetric box, so could be centered using `\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-.5\totalheight\relax}{$\ldots$}`), so I created a new version with it. However, it has a small left/right padding.